# Cannot get UIPinchGestureRecognizer to work

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, pinchzoom, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I can't seem to get this to work programatically.  I have a UIImageView which I want to make Draggable and Pinchable.  **Everything for the draggable part is working**, the pinch on the other hand doesn't seem to work.

My Custom UIImageView Class subclasses **UIImageView** and Implements **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate**

In my init functions I have the following:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.initializeGestures()

}


override init(image: UIImage?) {

    super.init(image: image)

    self.initializeGestures()

}

func initializeGestures() {

    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = true

    dragGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
    zoomGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePinch:")

    self.addGestureRecognizer(dragGesture)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(zoomGesture)

}
```

Followed by the following lines of code:

```
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {

    Scripts.log("PAN >>> DRAG ACTIVATED")
}


func handlePinch(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    Scripts.log("PINCH >>> ZOOM ACTIVATED")

    recognizer.view?.transform = CGAffineTransformScale((recognizer.view?.transform)!, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
    recognizer.scale = 1

}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    return true

}
```

Comment: add pinch gesture into pan gesture dependencies,

Comment: @SolaWing what do you mean by that?

Comment: two gesture conflict, to recognize pinch gesture, you need to add a dependency to pan gesture. so when pinch recognize failed, pan can be recognized.

Comment: @SolaWing I made some edits to the code and tried doing this if this is what you mean, but then they both don't work now -> dragGesture.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(zoomGesture)

Comment: forgive my error, pinch need 2 touch and can't be fail with 1 touch.   After I test, your need add `dragGesture.delegate = self`, so shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer will be call

Comment: @SolaWing Now it is working!  Thank you very much!!  I wish I could give you credit for the answer since you just replied to the comment, but thanks.